# Connecting Matlab with java Netbeans

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans, matlab-deployment

I have create a `Java` project in `Netbeans`. I used `Matlab` for the image processing part of my project. Now I need to connect `Matlab` to `Java`. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Follow the link https://matlabfreecode.wordpress.com/tag/run-matlab-on-netbean/

Comment: [MATLAB Compiler SDK](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-compiler-sdk/) (the Java part was previously the "MATLAB Builder JA" toolbox)